# Arrays with negative indices in FreePascal

Tags: arrays, associative-array, freepascal

I need to create an array with numerical indices and values. However, many of these indices are negative. (I have no control over that.) How would I go about doing this in FreePascal? Can dictionary objects take negative numbers as indices and values?  If possible, I would like to avoid turning the numbers into strings. Thanks.

[edit]

Also, there are gaps between the indices. The numbers are not continuous.

Comment: If you have a minimum/maximum value just use an old school array

Comment: Even if there are gaps in the numbering?

Comment: You can always make a continuous array and just ignore the additional elements

Comment: If you don't have a minimum/maximum, maybe you don't need and array, but a list.

Comment: I ended up using some arbitrary minimum and maximum that somewhat closely fits my data, then simply ignored the elements I didn't need. Thanks.